# How to pass VueJS data to another script?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm converting an established site over to VueJS but hit a stumbling block on the best way to achieve this.

It's using D3-Funnel (https://github.com/jakezatecky/d3-funnel) to draw a funnel chart but how do I pass VueJS data variables to the charts constructor?

```
<script>
const data = [
    { label: 'Step 1', value: this.step1 },
    { label: 'Step 2', value: this.step2 },
    .......
];
const options = {
    block: {
        dynamicHeight: true,
        minHeight: 15,
    },
};

const chart = new D3Funnel('#funnel');
chart.draw(data, options);
</script>
```

So I need to pass vue data variables into the values. My first thought is to move this into it's own function in the VueJS methods object and use the variables there using `this`.

Is there a better way of achieving this?

---------- Edit -------------

As per comments people wanted to see how I achieved this currently in vue. As already mentioned above I just created a function in the vue methods object and then call it.

```
methods : {
    drawChart(){
        const data = [
            { label: 'Step 1', value: 99999 },
            { label: 'Step 2', value: 9999 },
            .......
        ];
        const options = {
            block: {
                dynamicHeight: true,
                minHeight: 15,
            },
        };

        const chart = new D3Funnel('#funnel');
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
},
mounted(){
    this.drawChart();
}
```

Data is coming from an API and put into the vue data object.

```
data:{
    step1: 0,
    step2: 0,
    ....
},
methods:{
    getData(){
        axois.post......
        response{
            this.step1 = response.data.step1
            this.step2 = response.data.step2
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you tried with vue?

Comment: So where is this data actually coming from? Is it the data Object from the root component? And if so, how are you currently setting that data?

Comment: You probably want to make a funnel-chart component.

Comment: update post to answers questions in the comments

Comment: Your problem is to transfer data from componentA to componentB, right?

Comment: What do you mean by "another script"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it you are trying to pass information down to a component and use it. If you are using single file components and webpack you can do something like this which is put together with examples listed on the vue website.

You can also take a look at this guys [approach](https://medium.com/tyrone-tudehope/composing-d3-visualizations-with-vue-js-c65084ccb686)

**App.vue**

```
...
<my-d3-component :d3data="d3Data"></my-d3-component>
...
<script>
  import d3Component from 'path/to/component'
  var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      d3Data: {}
    },
    components: {
      'my-d3-component': d3Component
    }
  })
 </script>
```

**d3Component.vue**

```
<template>
  d3 html stuff goes here
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    props: ['d3Data'],
    data() {
      return {}
    },
    mounted: {
      const options = {
        block: {
            dynamicHeight: true,
            minHeight: 15,
        },
    };

    const chart = new D3Funnel('#funnel');
    chart.draw(this.d3Data, options);
  }
}
</script>
```